# Update Child Record via Apex Trigger

Tags: apex, trigger, soql

I'm trying to write a trigger that will update specific fields on child records if certain criteria are met on the parent object. I have two custom objects Sesaco_Contract__c (Master) and Receiving__c (Child). I have the following fields

Sesaco_Contract__r.Amount_Paid__c

Receiving__r.Include_in_Settlement__c (checkbox)

Receiving__r.Paid__c (checkbox)

On the Parent object (Sesaco_Contract__c) I want to check to see if "Amount_Paid__c" is changed and if it is, change "Paid__c" to True for any Receiving (child) record where "Include_in_Settlement__c" is True. I would also like to be able to set "Include_in_Settlement__c" to False as well. So, if a payment is made on the master record, any child records that have been set to include in a settlement have the "paid" cb ticked and the include in settlement cb unticked.

I think I have something that is close to what is needed but the console isn't letting me save due to the Receiving__r in the FROM part of my query.

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

```
    trigger markRecRptPaid on Sesaco_Contract__c (after update) {
 Set<ID> maids = new Set<ID>();
    Sesaco_Contract__c ma = [Select Id, Amount_Paid__c From Sesaco_Contract__c Where Crop_Year__c = 'system.Date.year.today()'];
    for(Sesaco_Contract__c sc : Trigger.new){
        // Access old record
        Sesaco_Contract__c oldMA = Trigger.oldMap.get(SC.Id);

        if(oldMA.Amount_Paid__c != sc.Amount_Paid__c){
            maids.add(sc.Id);
        }
     }
    List<Sesaco_Contract__c> updatedMA = [SELECT Id, Amount_Paid__c, (Select Id, Include_in_Settlement__c, Paid__c from Receiving__r)  FROM Sesaco_Contract__c WHERE Id in :maids];

    List<Receiving__c> recrptUpdate = new List<Receiving__c>();

    for (Sesaco_Contract__c sc : updatedMA){
        // Loop through each Related Receiving record
        for(Receiving__c rec : sc.Receiving__c){
            if(rec.Include_in_Settlement__c = True){
            rec.Include_in_Settlement__c = false;
            rec.Paid__c = True;
            recrptUpdate.add(rec);
            }
        }
    }
    update recrptUpdate;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below is my trim down approach -

```
trigger markRecRptPaid on Sesaco_contract__C (after update) {

Set<Id> maids = new Set<Id>();

 for(sesaco_Contract__c sc : Trigger.new){
if((Trigger.newmap.get(sc.id).Amount_Paid__c) != (Trigger.oldmap.get(Sc.id).amount_paid__c)
{
maids.add(sc.id);
}

if(!maids.isEmpty()){
List<Receiving__C> recrptUpdate = [select id,Include_in_Settlement__c,Paid__c from Receiving__c   where Sesaco_Contract__c in :maids];

 for (receiving__C rec : recrptUpdate) {

        rec.Include_in_Settlement__c = false;
        rec.Paid__c = True;
}
update recrptUpdate;
  }  
}
```

I don't think if(rec.Include_in_Settlement__c = True) is necessary. Please test this solution in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to look at the Child Relationship Name for that child object which is on the lookup field to the Master object

[image: child relationship name]

E.g. In the example above, Project Member looks up to Project - the child relationship name is what you need to append the __r to so that the final SOQL for me looks like this:

Select Id, (Select Name from Project_Members__r) from Project__c

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to explain the mystery of __r and __c, and how to spot the upward (child to parent) and downward (parent to child) relationships [in here with examples](http://11concepts.com/sfdc/blog/understanding-__c-and-__r/). Hope this helps in getting a little more clarity on the topic.